# Create NSDictionary with keys and values when selected UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, uicollectionview, key-value

I have a UICollectionView with thumbnails. When user selects one or multiple images at same time, I have to create NSDictionary with keys and values. Key has to be a specific name. This is the final result I need to get.

```
(
image[0] = 75829457,
image[1] = 03480923,
image[2] = 58924589
)
```

Values here are obviously image ids. How can I do that? I need to send that NSDictionary via POST request, which is not a problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: This rather seems to be an array, not a dictionary.

Comment: alright, then array. The question is how?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question very well. You can make an array using `NSArray *arr = @[ @9273535, @3651537894, @51436393 ];`...

Comment: If you going for a print out, a dictionary looks something like the following in the terminal

`{
    key1 = value1;
    key2 = value2;
}`

Comment: @H2CO3 That's the point. It has to be associative array which in Objective C I believe it's called NSDictionary. Made out of key/value pairs. Array as a list of objects won't work. The key name has to be "image[]".

Comment: @feliun That's pretty much what I'm looking for. In my question image[0] is key1 and 75829457 is value1. How do I get that out when user selects a cell in collection view.

Comment: What is image[0]? Is that an image? A string?

Comment: How you get it out depends on what your data structure is -- we can't answer that without more information.

Comment: @rdelmar image[0] should be a key. I'll try my best to rephrase my question. User can select multiple images. for each image I need to output something like this `image[0] = 58724395`. I'm not sure if i need nsarray or nsdictionary here but in this case image[0] is a key and 58724395 is value for that key. If user selects 2 images, then I need to get something like this `image[0] = 58724395, image[1] = 5871889`. The question is how do i compose something like that in didSelectItemAtIndexPath. The values are picture ids which i get from web service.

Comment: please let me know if I need to explain anything else to make it more clear. I know my questions is confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller, declare a member variable NSMutableString *mutableString. Initialize mutableString in your init method to be empty.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)aCollectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath)indexPath {
    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image[%d]", [indexPath row]];
    NSString *value = // get the picture id
    NSString *parameter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", key, value];

    if ([mutableString length] != 0)
        [mutableString appendString:@"&"];

    [mutableString appendString:parameter];
}
```

Then use an IBAction to confirm the selections, construct your POST request and send it, and then empty the mutable string.

Comment: The only data I have is that object value which is picture id. The web service is expecting me to send a basic post with NO JSON - something like this: `"image[0]=123&image[1]=345&image[2]=876"`. I thought i could get it via dictionary. Do you know how you could help me with that?

Comment: I'm getting (null) when I output the nsmutablestring.

Comment: Have you tried to inspect the parameter string before you append it into the mutable string?

Comment: Yes, that's fine. it outputs just as I want it to. And to be honest, when I declared NSMutableString you told me to set it as empty but that gives me error too so I din't set it as empty.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I forgot to init the MutableString. The only issue that I have here is that if user selects random images it gives me something like this: `"image[3]=345&image[8]=543&image[0]=775"`. It's  not in the order. I'll try to send it to web service to see if it works like that and will let you know. Unless if you have any other idea. And I have to thank you for all your help.

Comment: No need to order them. Thanks so much. Got it resolved with your help

Comment: Can you also suggest how to remove from the parameter from the string if someone selects the image and then deselects it right away. I know I have to implement the `- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method

Comment: In this case, I would suggest using a NSMutableDictionary instead of NSMutableString. That way, you can query if the key exists and if it does you can just remove it. You would also have to build the parameters string from the NSMutableDictionary in the IBAction.

Comment: Alright. Thanks a lot. I'll do that. If I get stuck I'll post a new question on SO. Hopefully you see it :)

Answer (score 1):

1. create a method to get ImageDictionary

   `- (NSDictionary *) dictionaryWithImageArray:(NSArray *)imageArrayID
   {
       NSMutableDictionary *imageDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
       for (int i=0; i<[imageArrayID count]; i++) {
           [imageDict setObject:[imageArrayID objectAtIndex:i] forKey:[NSString   stringWithFormat:@"image[%d]",i]];
       }
       return imageDict;
   }`
2. Convert that dict to json string

   `NSError *error;
   NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:<Dict from above>
                                                      options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                        error:&error];
   NSString *jsonString= nil;
   if (! jsonData) {
       NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
       jsonString = @"";
   } else {
       jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   }`
3. Set Http Body for your request

   `[request setHTTPBody: [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];`